# SQLite doesn't know about class

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm currently working on a Windows Forms application, and I would like to use a simple database which doesn't require a backing server or credentials to run, so I chose SQLite. But trying to get this thing to work so far was a nightmare.

Right now, I have a few, simple classes with simple properties, which I'd like to store in the database. I've appended the appropriate labels to everything (`[Table("")]` for classes, `[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]` for the Id property), but whenever I do `Connection.CreateTable(CreateFlags.AutoIncPK)` (it won't show the generic parameter, but it's there, I promise), it throws a NotSupportedException, saying "Don't know about MyProject.MyClass". I have also provided an empty, parameterless constructor in each class.

So, how do I make SQLite "know" about my class?

EDIT:
My Character.cs file:

```
[Table("Character")]
class Character
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string FilePath
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Character()
    {
    }
    public Character(string file)
    {
        this.FilePath = file;
        this.Name = FetchName(file);
    }

    private string FetchName(string file)
    {
        string[] fileHolder = File.ReadAllLines("\\chars\\" + file);
        foreach (string line in fileHolder)
        {
            if (line.ToLower().StartsWith("name"))
            {
                if (!line.Contains(';'))
                    return line.Split('=')[1].Trim().Trim('"');
                else return line.Split('=')[1].Split(';')[0].Trim().Trim('"');
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

My Database.cs file:

```
class Database
{
    private static SQLiteConnection Connection;
    private static string ConnectionString = "MyProject.sqlite";
    public Database()
    {
        if (!File.Exists("MyProject.sqlite"))
            System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyProject.sqlite");
        using (Connection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString))
        {              
            Connection.CreateTable<Character>(CreateFlags.AutoIncPK);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know about anyone else but whilst your question is verbose it lacks clarity. Can you re-state the problem with the code you are using.

Comment: I've updated my question with a sample class and my database handling class. Whenever I make a new instance of the Database class, and the constructor runs, the CreateTable method throws a NotSupportedException, saying it does not know the class. My question is, what am I missing from the code that SQLite needs to know about my class.

Comment: You are going to have to wait for someone knowledgeable in this area, but it doesn't appear that you are creating the `table`. The table within the database must have a name and a data structure ie data items with types and sizes. eg create table notes(note_text, note_number INTEGER);  I see no evidence of that.

Answer (score 0):

The class that describe your table has to be public.
In your example, the character class is not public.

You should change the declaration like this:

```
[Table("Character")]
public class Character
{
// your class code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late to answer the original question but since my Google-Fu led me here, I hope this will help others that encounter the same error message:

I started receiving this error message after I added as public static property to a class with a [table] attribute. After adding the [Ignore] attribute to the property, I no longer received the error message.