# Xamarin.Forms SQLite exception - don't know about <Custom Class>

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a new SQLite table in an SQLite database. However, whenever I run the code `db.CreateTable<Set>();`, I get a System.NotSupportedException. I viewed these other posts:

[Xamarin.Forms Sqlite-net NotSupportedException on ManyToOne relationship "Don't know about <model>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668282/xamarin-forms-sqlite-net-notsupportedexception-on-manytoone-relationship-dont)
Not my issue. I only have `using SQLite;` (SQLite-net-pcl), and when I remove that I get an error around `SQLiteConnection(dbPath)`.

[SQLite doesn't know about class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655217/sqlite-doesnt-know-about-class)
Also not a problem. Set is public, and contains no static elements.

Error Message:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about App1.Models.Set
```

Code for creating the db:

```
public static string dbPath = Path.Combine(
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
                "database.db3");

var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
            db.CreateTable<Set>();
            db.CreateTable<Card>();
```

Set class:

```
using SQLite;

namespace App1.Models
{
    [Table("Set")]
    public class Set
    {
        [MaxLength(64)]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [PrimaryKey]
        public string code { get; set; }
        public int amount { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(24)]
        public string plane { get; set; }

        public Set(string _name, string _code, int _amount, string _plane)
        {
            name = _name;
            code = _code;
            amount = _amount;
            plane = _plane;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only issue is creating the SET table? If you only create Card table, everything is ok?

Comment: Card has the same issue. If needed I can post that code as well.

Comment: Are you missing a reference to `App1.Models.Set` where you use  `db.CreateTable<Set>();`?  I created a new project and your code works well on my side.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your table.
'SET' is a keyword in SQLite.

You can find all the keywords in SQLite here.
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't solve the problem. Would be strange as well since I don't have the issue with the Card table.